# Docker without any https/SSL validation?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to turn off all https/ssl functionality when pulling images from the public docker registry?

I am stuck behind a corporate firewall which is screwing up all https traffic. (I am only getting invalid certificates...)

Answer (score -1):

In `/etc/default/docker` you are able to specify a HTTP proxy. If you are able to use a HTTP proxy then you should be able to set this to resolve your certificate issues.

By the looks of things you will also be able to define the environment variable `http_proxy` which docker will be able to read when you run `docker pull`

Comment: Answer should provide more details